# How do I calculate amounts from fields in different tables in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I want to keep track of credits/laway/rent to own info.

I have `[Clients]` `table`, `[Credit]` and a child `[payments]` table, to keep track of payments of multiple credits.

I want to make a Split form where I can see credit details ex. (type, amount of credit, amount of credit currently paid and last amount due) with a record of all payments done on the subform.

Now I ran into blockade when trying to use `sum()` or `Dsum()` to calculate the "amount of Credit currently paid" and "amount of credit due" in a text box on the form.

I think I´m missing something in the criteria part for I don´t know how to pass the current creditID key to group and calculate ???

the closest I´ve gotten is  `=DSuma("[MontoPagado]","Pagos","[IDCreditoFK]")` but this adds all up and I really need something like:

```
"amount due" =[table1]![Field1] - SUM([table2]![Field2]) Based on Current "creditID"
```

Its a basic credit/layaway plan payments database I hope someone can help for I have spent days with very Little sleep and this is the only thing holding me up...
Download copy here ----> https://mega.nz/#!gp0lSRLA

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He there,

You can use the DSum, but slightly different

```
=DSum("[MontoPagado]","[Pagos]","[IDCreditoFK]=" & [CreditorID])
```

Here, [CreditorID] should point towards the CreditorID control on your form

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Thank you! Verlaat you saved me, I don´t why I can´t grasp the concept or rules of building criterias and expresions?

Finally this worked perfect:

```
=[TotalDelMonto]-DSum("[MontoPagado]","[Pagos]","[IDCreditoFK]=" & [IdCreditos])
```